# How to Customize ShowLegend in AchartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am creating barchart using **achartengine** and showing multiple **bars** with **legendItem**
**but one problem arries in legend item showing not properly.**

When 2 to 5 **Xyseries** then not problem in Legend item show but when multiple series then graph not properly 
[image]
I have attached screenshot bargraph.
How to LegendItem show in group wise

i.e In LegendItem bottom part

```
       1LegendItem           2Legend
       3LegendItem           4LegendItem
```

Comment: `renderer.setFitLegend(true);`

Comment: i m applying this method but not working .Running after showing same above image attached

Comment: When adding 30 series to a chart, you have to have a good plan for the legend.Either hide it or set the text much smaller.